# Inherit methods from multiple uncooperative classes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, super

I've watch Raymond Hettingers [Pycon presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) and read his [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) as well as many questions here on Stackoverflow, but I've encounter a problem with inheritance that I can't seem to find an answer for. I'm going to use my problem as an example, but I'm interested in knowing why it doesn't work rather than how to fix it.

I have 3 classes I want to inherit from, both so that I can use their methods but also so that I can pass an instance of my own class in other functions or methods.

None of the inherited classes calls *super().__init__(**kwargs)* in their initializer, so I tried making an **adapter class** for each class, and a **Root class** to catch the remaining keyword arguments:

```
class Root(object):
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        pass


class Rect(Root):
    def __init__(self, pos=(0, 0), size=(16, 16), **kwargs):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, size)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Sprite(Root):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Surface(Root):
    def __init__(self, size, **kwargs):
        self.image = pygame.Surface(size).convert()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Gameobject(Rect, Sprite, Surface):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

This doesn't work because the methods of each class are not inherited to the GameObject class, rather it inherit just instances of each class.

My other attempt was to inherit both **Root** and their respective class from pygame for each **adapter class**, for example:

```
class Rect(Root, pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

This leads to an error: "*TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict*", which I've understood to be a conflict between the built-in implementation or something similar (not quite sure if I understood correctly).

How will I go on from here? Where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"the methods of each class are not inherited to the GameObject class, rather it inherit just instances of each class"* - that's because you're creating instances of them as attributes, not actually inheriting their behaviour. I don't think inheritance is the best approach for whatever it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When just thinking about it I do believe that this approach would improve the rest of my code, but even if it's not the best way I'm still curious to why this don't work. I'm really trying to get a grasp of inheritance and am afraid I'm missing some basics.